# matplotlib marker type order not consistent after each run?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Without changing any code, the graph plotted will be different. Correct at the first run in a fresh bash, disordered in the next runs. (maybe it can cycle back to correct order)

To be specific:
Environment: MacOS Mojave 10.14.2, python3.7.1 installed through homebrew.
To do: Plot `scatter` for two or three sets of data on the same `axes`, each with a different `markertype` and different `colors`. Plot customised legend showing which data set each `markertype` represents.

I am sorry I don't have enough time to prepare a testable code (for now), but this part seems to be the problem:

```
markerTypes = cycle(['o', 's', '^', 'd', 'p', 'P', '*'])
strainLegends = []
strains = list(set([idx.split('_')[0] for idx in pca2Plot.index]))
for strain in strains:
    # markerType is fixed here, and shouldn't be passed on to the next python run anyway.
    markerType = next(markerTypes)

    # strainSamples connects directly to strain variable, then data is generated from getting strainSamples:
    strainSamples = [sample for sample in samples if
                     sample.split('_')[0] == strain]
    xData = pca2Plot.loc[strainSamples, 'PC1']
    yData = pca2Plot.loc[strainSamples, 'PC2']
    # See pictures below, data is correctly identified from source

    # both scatter and legend instance use the same fixed markerType
    ax.scatter(xData, yData, c=drawColors[strainSamples],
               s=40, marker=markerType, zorder=3)
    strainLegends.append(Line2D([0], [0], marker=markerType, color='k',
                                markersize=10,
                                linewidth=0, label=strain))
    # print([i for i in ax.get_children() if isinstance(i, PathCollection)])

ax.legend(handles=strainLegends)
```

As you can see the `markerType` and `strain` data are correlated with the data.

For the first run with `python3 my_code.py` in bash, it creates a correct picture: see the circle represents A, square represents B
[image: see the circle represents A, square represents B]
A = circle, B = square. See the square around `(-3, -3.8)`, this data point is from dataset B.

While if I run the code again within the same terminal `python3 my_code.py`
[image]
Note A and B completely massed up, un-correlated.
Now as the legend: A = square, B = circle. Again see the data point `(-3, -3.8)` which comes from dataset B, now annotated as A.

If I run the code again, it might produce another result.

Here is the code I used to generate annotation:

```
dictColor = {ax: pd.Series(index=pca2Plot.index), }
HoverClick = interactionHoverClick(
    dictColor, fig, ax)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", HoverClick.hover)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", HoverClick.click)
```

In class `HoverClick`, I have

```
def hover(self, event):
    if event.inaxes != None:
        ax = event.inaxes
        annot = self.annotAxs[ax]
        # class matplotlib.collections.PathCollection, here refere to the scatter plotting event (correct?)
        drawingNum = sum(isinstance(i, PathCollection)
                         for i in ax.get_children())
        # print([i for i in ax.get_children() if isinstance(i, PathCollection)])

        plotSeq = 0
        jump = []
        indInd = []
        indIndInstances = []
        for i in range(drawingNum):
            sc = ax.get_children()[i]
            cont, ind = sc.contains(event)
            jump.append(len(sc.get_facecolor()))
            indIndInstances.append(ind['ind'])
            if cont:
                plotSeq = i
                indInd.extend(ind['ind'])

        # here plotSeq is the index of last PathCollection instance that program find my mouse hovering on a datapoint of it.
        sc = ax.get_children()[plotSeq]
        cont, ind = sc.contains(event)

        if cont:
            try:
                exist = (indInd[0] in self.hovered)
            except:
                exist = False
            if not exist:
                hovered = indInd[0]
                pos = sc.get_offsets()[indInd[0]]

                textList = []
                for num in range(plotSeq + 1):
                    singleJump = sum(jump[:num])
                    textList.extend([self.colorDict[ax].index[i + singleJump]
                                     for i in indIndInstances[num]])
                text = '\n'.join(textList)
                annot.xy = pos
                annot.set_text(text)
                annot.set_visible(True)
                self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if annot.get_visible():
                annot.set_visible(False)
                self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
# hover
```

Note that I annotated the code for print each instances. This is tested because I thought it might be the order of instances that has been changed throughout other part of code. But the result showed in both correct and wrong cases, the order was not changed.

Does anyone knows what happened?
Anyone have experienced this before?
If I need to clean the memory in the end of the code, what should I do?

Comment: Can you provide a (complete) [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It looks like the plot itself is correct, only the annotations are wrong. But the code you show does not have annotations in it, so one cannot find out why that happens.

Comment: Because I really shouldn't put my data here, so I need time to generate false data and that takes some time, but I will do it later. But @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, the annotation I get from a pandas DataFrame which is being loaded every time from hard disk when I run the code. I modified the question to show what is in `strains`, and for each run the `strains` will be the same if I pass the same data. `strains = ['A', 'B']`, each datapoint is annotated as `f'A_{number}'`

Comment: I mean in your code, there is no line line `ax.annotate(..)` so one cannot find out why it fails.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You are right. I added the annotation part of my script.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code is incomplete it is difficult to say for sure, but it seems that the order of markers is being messed up by the `cycle` iterator. Why don't you just try:

```
markerTypes = ['o', 's', '^']
strainLegends = []

for strain, markerType in zip(strains, markerTypes):
    strainSamples = [sample for sample in samples if sample.split('_')[0] == strain]
    xData = pca2Plot.loc[strainSamples, 'PC1']
    yData = pca2Plot.loc[strainSamples, 'PC2']
    ax.scatter(xData, yData, c=drawColors[strainSamples], s=40, marker=markerType, zorder=3)
    strainLegends.append(Line2D([0], [0], marker=markerType, color='k',
                                markersize=10,
                                linewidth=0, label=strain))
ax.legend(handles=strainLegends)
```

This of course assumes that `strains` and `markerTypes` are of the same length and the markers are in the same position in the list as the strain value you want to assign them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I sometimes have different number of datasets to plot, thus I would like to use a cycler. Do you know why the cycler gives different results in different program runs even when I re-assign the cycler each time with a list?

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue caused by a de-replication process I made in `strains`.

```
# wrong code:
strains = list(set([idx.split('_')[0] for idx in pca2Plot.index]))

# correct code:
strains = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([idx.split('_')[0] for idx in pca2Plot.index]))
```

Thus the question I asked was not a valid question. Thanks and sorry for everyone looked into this.